# how to pure `chinese` key in nginx?

Tags: caching, nginx

I got this line in `nginx conf`, other line omitted

```
location /{
    uwsgi_cache_key $request_uri;
}
```

and pure section

```
location ~ /_purge(/.*$){
    uwsgi_cache_purge  mycache $1;
}
```

It works well for url like `http://host/test` and `http://host/_purge/test`
but `http://host/测试` with cache can't be purged by `http://host/_purge/测试` or `http://host/_purge/%E6%B5%8B%E8%AF%95`

**How to purge `http://host/测试` cache ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The var `$request_uri` in nginx is url encoded actually.
so the key cached is `/%E6%B5%8B%E8%AF%95`

but whether request to `http://host/_purge/测试` or `http://host/_purge/%E6%B5%8B%E8%AF%95` is the same. they are urlunescaped after the match `/_purge(/.*$)`. The `$1` actually is `/测试`.
So we can't purge the cache.

**Solving:**
extra module needed: https://github.com/openresty/set-misc-nginx-module#installation

```
location /{
    set_unescape_uri $key $request_uri;
    uwsgi_cache_key $key;
}
```